# Continuing Game From Last Level Reached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've searched around the Unity3d and StackOverflow websites looking for something relevant to what I want to do. However, I've come up blank in my research. I'm going to ask this question and show what I want to do and either its doable or not.

```
 curLvl = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
```

What I'm trying to do is store the current scene in a variable. To do this, I need to know what to declare the variable as. For example,

```
 private GameObject curLvl = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
 // Below Doesn't work for me - SceneAsset doesn't seem to exist
 private SceneAsset curLvl = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
```

I have a continue button set up and I want it to read this information upon click. Which I have a function set up with an OnClick event handler. So really all I need is this one piece of information.

Note - I'm using Unity 2018.2.18f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`buildIndex`* field returns a **integer**
Then you can call the method LoadScene and pass the index number of the scene you wanna load/reload through params

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-buildIndex.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html